# Linux brouting with ebtables, filter and forward EAPoL frames

Tags: linux, iptables, ethernet

Given 3 ethernet interfaces, I'd like to accomplish this:

```
eth0 -> WAN
eth1 -> EAPoL authenticator
eth2 -> IP Nat to private network
```

In this scenario, I would like ebtables to filter and forward ethernet frames of type 0x888E (EAPoL) to/from the WAN through eth1 which will have the EAPoL authenticator connected. The remaining traffic I would like to IP NAT to eth2.

I was reading about brouting here:

http://ebtables.netfilter.org/examples/basic.html#ex_brouter

Though it's not clear how I use the above for layer 2 filtering.

Instead, what i've tried so far was to create a bridge with eth0 and eth1 and then an ebtables filtering rule so that only EAPoL traffic arrives on eth1:

```
ebtables -t filter -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p 0x888e -j ACCEPT
ebtables -t filter -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j DROP
ebtables -t filter -A FORWARD -o eth0 -p 0x888e -j ACCEPT
ebtables -t filter -A FORWARD -o eth0 -j DROP
```

Then I IP NAT between eth0 and eth2:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0-j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
```

unfortunately, I can't get BOTH of these to work at the same time, only one or the other.

Any ideas? Appreciate any thoughts or tips