# How to establish a man-in-the-middle scenario with ebtables and iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, nat, netfilter

For testing and educational purposes I want so set up a man-in-the-middle scenario as follows:

- Host T is the target host that is to be "cloned"
- Host M is the man in the middle with interfaces `eth0` and `eth1`; M is connected to the network via `eth0` and to T via `eth1`.

The point of the setup is that T must be able to answer some requests (particularly 802.1X authentication via EAPoL, thus M is using T as an authentication oracle). Specifically, by default T would be connected to the network and authenticate itself via 802.1X while M would be denied access. Conversely, the user has administrative access to M but not to T. The purpose is to let M appear to be T while performing network diagnosis which would not be possible from T due to lack of privileges.

There are two possible approaches:

1. Write a program (e.g. python with scapy or C with libpcap) that copies the relevant frames forth and back.
2. Use `ebtables` and `iptables`.

The question here focuses on 2 and simply goes like: How to accomplish the desired result?

### What I tried so far

The first step was to bridge `eth0` and `eth1` (e.g. attach them to `br0`). Without any `ebtables`/`iptables` rules T is visible to the network as if connected directly to it. Then, since the focus is mostly to impersonate T on IPv4, I established the following rule:

```
ebtables -A FORWARD -p IPv4 -j DROP
```

This rule prevents IPv4 traffic to cross the bridge. Now, to impersonate T, M must do some NATing at layers 2 and 3:

```
# interception of incoming packets for T:
ebtables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p IPv4 -d $TARGET_MAC_ADDR -j dnat --to-destination $MY_ETH0_MAC_ADDR
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d $TARGET_IP4_ADDR -j DNAT --to-destination $MY_ETH0_IP4_ADDR
# spoofing of outgoing packets as coming from T:
ebtables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p IPv4 -s $MY_ETH0_MAC_ADDR -j snat --to-source $TARGET_MAC_ADDR
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s $MY_ETH0_IP4_ADDR -j SNAT --to-source $TARGET_IP4_ADDR
```

My naive thought was that this should do. But it doesn't. Apart from "disconnecting" T, M does not at all behave like T. Especially, `iptables -t nat -L -v -n` shows that SNAT rules are triggered as expected, but the DNAT rule is inert (i.e. 0 packets, no matter what happens). What am I missing here?

### Notes

The problem is similar to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/308061/64248) but the setup is not the same.

In a comment Rui points out that some protocols are prone to trouble when NATed. This is the case if a router is masquerading hosts in an upstream network (a.k.a. *Cone NAT*). However, this is not the point here. In this scenario NAT is used to masquerade M as T while shading T. M simply drops T's packets (see first ebtables rule)

### Background

802.1X (more precisely 802.1X-2010) provides only authentication, but no subsequent "channel" security. This is as if the TLS handshake results in NULL encryption and authentication - the "supplicant" proves *at the time of the authentication* its authenticity, but the "session" following the authentication can be hijacked.

The remedy for wired connections is MACsec (a.k.a 802.1ae, which is part of 802.1X-2014). The wireless pendant to MACsec is WPA/WPA2. Amazingly, even the cheapest piece of hardware can master WPA2, while high end switches that are capable of MACsec are considerably more expensive than those without.

Among other things the described scenario shows that 802.1X without MACsec is worthless.

Comment: Some protocols also include IP information inside it, and are sensitive to NAT, other protocols like RADIUS might do certificate checking. NAT is not the better way to do a man in the middle attack. There is also MAC spoofing or more advanced setups of intercepting requests via bridging to a machine in another physical network. I suspect you might have more success discussing those scenarios in our sister site security.stackexchange.com than here.

Comment: Rui, based on my experience with security stackexchange U&L is a much better place for my question. (I once dared to ask about hydra there...)

Comment: Rui, I know that some protocols are problematic in the face of NAT, but this is not the point here. Machine T is actually to be quiet, machine M is the one that talks to the net (impersonating T).

Comment: 8021.X only does auth and accounting, then the traffic usually goes via somewhere else (an AP or router). What do you intend to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with trying approach 1), I just finished writing an EAPOL proxy (https://github.com/kangtastic/peapod). It will even change the MAC address of eth0 to match that of your target automatically if you like, although I'd do it manually. It seems you can configure a static IPv4 address on eth0 and obtain connectivity, which is good, because my proxy doesn't handle any Layer 3 stuff. Anyway, based on your description, I'm sure it would work for your situation. There are some other EAPOL proxies, mostly in Python, that would probably work just as well if you look.

If your EAPOL supplicant also needs to "register" itself with the upstream network once the session is up via DHCP to get IPv4 connectivity, things get a little more complicated depending on whether the upstream network requires a certain hostname, client identifier, etc. to be sent in the DHCP requests. Worst case, you'd have to configure dhclient on M to send exactly the same options as the DHCP client on T. It's annoying but you can get the two to be identical if you're persistent enough. Cloning the supplicant's MAC to eth0 helps there too.

If you're set on approach 2) using eb/iptables - sorry, I can't be of much help there. I'll just say that EAPOL will not cross a Linux software bridge by default, because the EAPOL multicast group address, 01-80-C2-00-00-03, is not forwarded by 802.1D-compliant bridges. The solution to this is:

```
echo 8 > /sys/class/net/brX/bridge/group_fwd_mask
```

(Why 8 and not some other value? Because https://interestingtraffic.nl/2017/11/21/an-oddly-specific-post-about-group_fwd_mask/)

You got T to authenticate through your bridge, so you know that already, but others might not :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Man in The Middle Proxy - https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy ? It will do everything you are asking.

```
wget https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/releases/download/v2.0.2/mitmproxy-2.0.2-linux.tar.gz
```

Or with PIP

```
pip3 install mitmproxy
```

Then run it:

```
./mitmproxy --host
```

Configure the proxy in your browser and it will MITM all the traffic you want.